# Is there a JavaScript strcmp()?

Tags: javascript, string, strcmp

Can anyone verify this for me? JavaScript does not have a version of strcmp(), so you have to write out something like:

```
 ( str1 < str2 ) ? 
            -1 : 
             ( str1 > str2 ? 1 : 0 );
```

Comment: You're not alone - [other people have done this before](http://phpjs.org/functions/strcmp:533). The [PHP.JS project](http://phpjs.org/) actually has done this for many other common functions, as well. It's a handy resource.

Answer (score 157):

What about

```
str1.localeCompare(str2)
```

Comment: localeCompare() looked good, but it looked like it was MS-only, or not in the standard at best.

Comment: what standard are you looking at? it seems to be in ECMA-262 standard section 15.5.4.9, as well as in the mozilla Javascript reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML)

Comment: newacct is absolutely correct. This seems to be ECMAScript standard. Probably the best solution in this case.

Comment: `localeCompare()` sometimes behaves differently on each browser.

Comment: @VardaElentári: Only for characters that have no lexical ordering in the given locale. For characters that *do* and browsers that don't restrict what parts of Unicode they use, results are consistent and [defined by ECMA-402 and Unicode](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sec-implementation-dependencies).

Comment: Update 9 years later- seems this has partial support in IE6+ (covering the single-arg version), full support in IE11, and all other decent browsers of course support it: https://caniuse.com/#search=localecompare

Comment: `localeCompare()` compares by locale, the `>`/`<` compare by character plain ASCII/unicode numerical value. They are not interchangeable and like pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17765169/2750743), the performance is different by magnitude.

Answer (score 45):

Javascript doesn't have it, as you point out.

A quick search came up with:

```
function strcmp ( str1, str2 ) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Waldo Malqui Silva
    // +      input by: Steve Hilder
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +    revised by: gorthaur
    // *     example 1: strcmp( 'waldo', 'owald' );
    // *     returns 1: 1
    // *     example 2: strcmp( 'owald', 'waldo' );
    // *     returns 2: -1

    return ( ( str1 == str2 ) ? 0 : ( ( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
}
```

from http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_strcmp/

Of course, you could just add localeCompare if needed:

```
if (typeof(String.prototype.localeCompare) === 'undefined') {
    String.prototype.localeCompare = function(str, locale, options) {
        return ((this == str) ? 0 : ((this > str) ? 1 : -1));
    };
}
```

And use `str1.localeCompare(str2)` everywhere, without having to worry wether the local browser has shipped with it. The only problem is that you would have to add support for [`locales` and `options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Example:_Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) if you care about that.

Comment: I think this is a nice way of handling it (feature detection and polyfill FTW), but if micro speed performance is so important, as for the need of this method, then I am a little puzzled that `==` is used and not `===` since the latter avoid type conversion and hence is that micro second faster.

Comment: a note on the polyfill-- localeCompare is not case-sensitive, so to make the polyfill also not case-sensitive you might do something like-  `var a = this.toUpperCase(); var b = str.toUpperCase(); return ((a == b) ? 0 : ((a > b) ? 1 : -1));`

Answer (score 28):

[`localeCompare()` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14677060/1397061), so if you don't care about the "correct" ordering of non-English-character strings, try your original method or the cleaner-looking:

```
str1 < str2 ? -1 : +(str1 > str2)
```

This is an order of magnitude faster than `localeCompare()` on my machine.

The `+` ensures that the answer is always numeric rather than boolean.

Comment: Two bugs: does not return 0 for str1 == str2, does not return 1 for str1 > str2

Comment: @stackunderflow What are you suggesting that it returns in those cases?

Comment: @1" I suggest it should be useful as a comparefun in [Array.prototype.sort](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11), but actually the values need not be 1 and -1, just negative or positive as I just reread the standard.

Comment: @stackunderflow I'm using it successfully in a sorting function.  What is the bug that you are experiencing?

Comment: @stackunderflow that line is correct, it returns -1 if str1<str2 and then the return value of str1>str2 which from boolean to int is 0 or 1.

Comment: This will return -1, false, or true instead of -1, 0, or 1. To get it to return numbers always, tweak it like this:
    str1 < str2 ? -1 : +(str1 > str2)

Comment: One more thing (I'm using this in code I'm writing right now, so I've been perfecting it): just be aware that this is a case-sensitive comparison ('Foo' will come before 'bar' but 'Bar' will come after 'foo'). That corresponds to OP's question about strcmp, but many people may come here looking for a case-agnostic comparison.

Comment: Here's an even cleaner-looking expression: `(str1 > str2) - (str1 < str2)`

Answer (score 9):

```
var strcmp = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric:true, sensitivity:'base'}).compare;
```

Usage: `strcmp(string1, string2)`

Result: `1` means string1 is bigger, `0` means equal, `-1` means string2 is bigger.

This has higher performance than `String.prototype.localeCompare`

Also, `numeric:true` makes it do logical number comparison

Comment: Here are some jsperf results https://jsperf.com/localecompare-vs-intl-collator  https://jsperf.com/localecompare-vs-intl-collator

Comment: @Anonymous This is the opposite of strcmp

Answer (score 1):

from this [How to Check if Two Strings are Equal in JavaScript](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/string/javascript-string-equals/) article:

1. Generally, if your strings contain only ASCII characters, you use the `===` operator to check if they are equal.
2. But when your strings contain characters that include combining characters(eg. `e + ◌́ = é`), you normalize them first before comparing for equality as follows-
   `s1.normalize() === s2.normalize()`

Answer (score 0):

So I fell into this rabbit hole and wrote some tests to build an intuition, the result's are weird.
tldr it looks like localeCompare Performs a to lowercase that
the equality operators do not. This causes "ff" to be >= "ZZ" but locale Compare returns -1 becuse "ff" <= 'zz'

For best results view logs of code in browser console ctrl + shift + i

second snip it hides hand tests so you see some random ones.

Home this helps someone

```js
function stringBench(n, bench, min = 10, len = 10, logDif = false) {
  function makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength));
    }
    return result;

  }

  var a = [];
  var b = [];
  var pool = {};
  let rle = [];
  let rlc = [];

  let now;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pool[i] = (makeid(min + Math.floor(Math.random() *
      len))); //10-20ish

  }
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    a[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    b[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }

  console.log("now testin le vs lc on a pool of", n, " with this many samples ", bench);
  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  let lcDelta = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "lc localeCompare in ", lcDelta);


  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rle[i] = pool[a[i]] <= pool[b[i]];
  }
  let leDelta = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "le (<=) compares in ", leDelta)

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pool[i] = (makeid(min + Math.floor(Math.random() *
      len))); //10-20ish

  }
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    a[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    b[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }


  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rle[i] = pool[a[i]] <= pool[b[i]];
  }
  let leDelta2 = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "le (<=) compares in ", leDelta2)

  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  let lcDelta2 = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "lc localeCompare in ", lcDelta2);

  function testCmp(a, b, log = true) {
    let le = a <= b;
    let ge = a >= b;
    let lc = a.localeCompare(b);
    let l = a < b;
    let g = a > b;
    if (le && ge) console.assert(lc == 0, 'le && ge -> == -> lc == 0,')
    if (le) console.assert(lc <= 0, 'le-> lc <= 0')
    if (ge) console.assert(lc >= 0, 'ge-> lc >= 0')
    if (l) console.assert(lc < 0, 'l=>lc < 0')
    if (g) console.assert(lc > 0, 'g-> lc > 0')
    if (!log) return;
    console.log(`Compare:  ${a} le ${b} `, a <= b);
    console.log(`Compare:  ${a} ge ${b}`, a >= b);
    console.log(`Compare: ${a} lc ${b}`, a.localeCompare(b));
  }

  let c = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    if (rle[i] != rlc[i] <= 0) {
      c++;
      testCmp(pool[a[i]], pool[b[i]], true);
      console.warn(pool[a[i]], ' le != lc <= 0 ', pool[b[i]]);

    }


    // rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  console.warn(' le != lc  out of bench, num diffs: ', c);


  testCmp('ff', 'ff')
  testCmp('ff', 'fa')
  testCmp('ff', 'fz')
  testCmp('ff', 'fff')
  testCmp('ff', 'ffa')
  testCmp('ff', 'ffz')
  testCmp('ff', 'a')
  testCmp('ff', 'z')
  testCmp('ff', 'f')
  testCmp('ff', 'zff')
  testCmp('ff', 'aff')
  testCmp('ff', 'ZZ')
  testCmp('ff', 'AA')
  testCmp('FF', 'ZZ')
  testCmp('FF', 'ff')
  testCmp('FF', 'AA')
  testCmp('ff', 'ZZZ')

  console.log("Dif le - lc = ", leDelta2 - lcDelta2);

  console.log("avg le ms/Mops = ", (leDelta + leDelta2) / (bench / 1000000));
  console.log("avg lc ms/Mops = ", (lcDelta + lcDelta2) / (bench / 1000000));


  console.log("Dif  - lc = ", leDelta2 - lcDelta2);

};
stringBench(1000, 5000, 1, 3, true);
// stringBench(1000000, 1000000);//nothing is equire
// stringBench(1000, 100000000);
// stringBench(1000000, 100000000, 3, 5);
// stringBench(1000000, 100000000, 15, 20);
```

```js
function stringBench(n, bench, min = 10, len = 10, logDif = false) {
  function makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength));
    }
    return result;


  }

  var a = [];
  var b = [];
  var pool = {};
  let rle = [];
  let rlc = [];

  let now;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pool[i] = (makeid(min + Math.floor(Math.random() *
      len))); //10-20ish

  }
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    a[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    b[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }

  console.log("now testin le vs lc on a pool of", n, " with this many samples ", bench);
  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  let lcDelta = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "lc localeCompare in ", lcDelta);


  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rle[i] = pool[a[i]] <= pool[b[i]];
  }
  let leDelta = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "le (<=) compares in ", leDelta)

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pool[i] = (makeid(min + Math.floor(Math.random() *
      len))); //10-20ish

  }
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    a[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    b[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }


  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rle[i] = pool[a[i]] <= pool[b[i]];
  }
  let leDelta2 = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "le (<=) compares in ", leDelta2)

  now = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  let lcDelta2 = Date.now() - now;
  console.log("Performed ", bench, "lc localeCompare in ", lcDelta2);

  function testCmp(a, b, log = true) {
    let le = a <= b;
    let ge = a >= b;
    let lc = a.localeCompare(b);
    let l = a < b;
    let g = a > b;
    if (le && ge) console.assert(lc == 0, 'le && ge -> == -> lc == 0,')
    if (le) console.assert(lc <= 0, 'le-> lc <= 0')
    if (ge) console.assert(lc >= 0, 'ge-> lc >= 0')
    if (l) console.assert(lc < 0, 'l=>lc < 0')
    if (g) console.assert(lc > 0, 'g-> lc > 0')
    if (!log) return;
    console.log(`Compare:  ${a} le ${b} `, a <= b);
    console.log(`Compare:  ${a} ge ${b}`, a >= b);
    console.log(`Compare: ${a} lc ${b}`, a.localeCompare(b));
  }

  let c = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
    if (rle[i] != rlc[i] <= 0) {
      c++;
      testCmp(pool[a[i]], pool[b[i]], true);
      console.warn(pool[a[i]], ' le != lc <= 0 ', pool[b[i]]);

    }


    // rlc[i] = pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  }
  console.warn(' le != lc  out of bench, num diffs: ', c);



  testCmp('ff', 'fa')
  testCmp('ff', 'fz')
  testCmp('ff', 'ZZ')



  console.log("Dif le - lc = ", leDelta2 - lcDelta2);

  console.log("avg le ms/Mops = ", (leDelta + leDelta2) / (bench / 1000000));
  console.log("avg lc ms/Mops = ", (lcDelta + lcDelta2) / (bench / 1000000));







  console.log("Dif  - lc = ", leDelta2 - lcDelta2);


  // for (let i = 0; i < bench; i++) {
  //     rlc[i] != rle[i]
  //     pool[a[i]].localeCompare(pool[b[i]]);
  // }
  //
  // console.log(makeid(5));
};
stringBench(1000, 5000, 1, 3, true);
// stringBench(1000000, 1000000);//nothing is equire
// stringBench(1000, 100000000);
// stringBench(1000000, 100000000, 3, 5);
// stringBench(1000000, 100000000, 15, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, this is about 10% faster than using a pair of ternary statements on the same set of randomly selected words.

```
function strcmp( a, b ) {
    for( let i=0 ; i<Math.min( a.length, b.length ) ; i++ ) {
        const n = a.charCodeAt(i) - b.charCodeAt(i);
        if( n ) return  n && ( ( n>>31 ) || 1 );
    }
    const n = a.length - b.length;
    return  n && ( ( n>>31 ) || 1 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
String.prototype.strcmp = function(s) {
    if (this < s) return -1;
    if (this > s) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, to compare s1 with 2:

```
s1.strcmp(s2)
```

Comment: It would help if you said why they shouldn't do what they did. I could understand if they were altering how an existing function method worked, but in this case they are adding a new one.

Comment: Extending prototypes unconditionally like this is generally a big no-no.