# Comparison of 2 string literals in JS. Is it valid?

Tags: javascript, qt4.8

Doesn't JS allow comparison of 2 string literals? e.g:

```
"Some String" == "Some String"
```

If not, was it different in some previous versions?

Background of the question:
I use ECMA-Script in Qt 4. My DSL-Engine transforms parts of DSL-Scripts to JS and evaluates it. Since I moved from Qt4.7.4 (LGPL) to Qt4.8.4 (Commercial) the evaluation  of the code above fails.
In Qt4.7.4 I used to get true/false. Now the QScriptEngine::evaluate says the syntax was not correct.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: does it say any more specific about the syntax being "not correct"? Is it disallowing `==` and requiring `===` instead? That syntax should be perfectly valid in all JS engines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript

Comment: @AlexWayne: Thank you! The error was in my DSL-engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, js allows comparisons of 2 string literals.

`"Some String" == "Some String"` should always return true. Some examples of the surrounding code might help give some more insight.

Comment: This doesn't answer the syntax issue. Leave a comment if you want to ask for more information.

Comment: +1: Yes, indeed this works in JS. My DSL had an error. Thank you, and thanks to everyone!