# how to alphabetise an array in javascript using a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bubble-sort, alphabetized

This is the JavaScript code to alphabetically sort the array, however i was searching for a way to bubble sort each item one at a time using a loop. please can you suggest a way of doing this or another alternative to sort()

```
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Scanner", "Moniter", "Projector", "USB", "Keyboard"]
document.getElementById("alphabetical.order").innerHTML = products;
function alphabetical() {
    products.rsort();
    document.getElementById("alphabetical.order").innerHTML = products;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `sort`?

Comment: I was wondering if there was any other ways of doing it

Comment: There are, but the ones that spring to mind are massively impractical. Use `sort` that's what it is there for.

Comment: if you're interested in how to sort on your own, you can take a look at this page: it shows an animation of how the sorting algorithms work and show pseudocode with it: https://visualgo.net/sorting

Comment: thank you, this was really helpful to learn how to sort integers with a loop however how could i use that to implement the use of string?

Comment: well, if the pseudocode says something like `if leftElement > rightElement` you do the same with strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript

Comment: would it make sense to assign values to the strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
products.sort(function(a, b) {  
    return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
});
```