# Can I use triple equals for JavaScript string comparison?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, triple-equals

This is an extremely basic question, I know, but I couldn't understand what's going on from Google and Stack Overflow.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179366/is-there-a-javascript-strcmp?lq=1) to learn how to compare strings in JavaScript. Neither mentioned triple equals (`===`) in their answers, and said that it's better to use your own function (`str1 < str2 ? -1 : str1 > str2`).

However, going through explanations about `===` in Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript?lq=1)), the answers contain string comparisons.
From what I saw in those answers, `===` does work for string comparisons, so why wasn't it included in the string comparison answers?

I'm just trying to expand my knowledge in JavaScript.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Yes, `===` can compare two strings, giving `true` or `false` as a result. The other examples you saw were talking about comparing strings when *sorting* lists of them.

Comment: You're correct. Thanks!

Comment: i dont think theres any advantage in using `===` instead of `==` when comparing thing you KNOW are going to be strings.  `===` is usually for comparing things that will be multiple types.  IE.  `'0' !== 0`.  I assume `==` is faster as well, but I'm much to lazy to find you benchmarks to back that up.

Comment: You should only use === when the data type of the value matters, meaning when it could result in an undesirable behavior. Like if something requires a 0 to calculate but instead gets a false or a string '0' which can result in an inaccurate calculation or a string value that could choke a process. Triple-equals are so abused nowadays in JavaScript, I've had to fix multiple bugs in committed code to change the === to == when it wasn't necessary and caused problems (meaning it didn't matter what the data type was but checking the data type of '0' vs 0 caused the process to choke).

Answer (score 6):

```
var str1 = "1";
var str2 = 1;
if (str1 == str2) {
      //Below code executes as it's true.
      console.log("Yes, value of both are equal.");
}

if (str1 === str2) {
     //Below code never executes as it's false.
     console.log("No, both are not equal as type differs.");
}
```

`==` compares value but `===` compares value as well as type.
`===` can be used as string comparison but if you are sure that you are just comparing string then `==` should be sufficient. `===` is just a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the example but I know what's the difference between `===` and `==`, that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both methods to compare strings, it just that you use `===` when you want to compare value AND type. what else is your query?