# How do I compare large decimal numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that looks like this:

```
function getValuesGreaterThan(num, values);
```

It'll return an array of the values.

Normally this is straightforward, but the values are stored in an array of strings: `[..., "1643764147.7500000000", "1643764147.7600000000382333388888", "1643764147.7700000000", ...]`. I want to make sure the output of `getValuesGreaterThan` isn't affected by precision issues or coercion quirks.

These *decimal numbers* come from a system call to a bash shell then are read in as strings. Sometimes these numbers are [beyond the limitations of JavaScript `Number`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#numbers):

> In JavaScript, numbers are implemented in [double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (i.e., a number between ±2^−1022 and ±2^+1023, or about ±10^−308 to ±10^+308, with a numeric precision of 53 bits). Integer values up to ±2^53 − 1 can be represented exactly.

I've learned that JavaScript has a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type, but I can't find anything about a `BigReal` or a `BigDecimal`, etc. This question spawned from [a similar question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410746/how-do-i-compare-unix-timestamps-in-javascript) (as an aside, there are some examples of what I've tried there), and a comment informed me that there are libraries for this:

> With a quick search I've found [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js), [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) and [math.js](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs) which seem could do the job.

But given that I only need the comparison operators (technically, I only need `>`), I'm wondering if there is an easy way to implement a solution without adding a library*.

How do I compare large decimal numbers in JavaScript?

---

*: One of the reasons I want to avoid libraries is because my `getValuesGreaterThan` code runs as a bash script with a `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node` shebang at the top. Adding a library would require bringing in a `package.json` a `node_modules` dir, potentially a `tsconfig.json`, etc. If I could compare large decimals in vanilla JS/TS, it avoids a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Grab the part of a library you need? E.g., js-big-decimal is broken up more than decimal.js is.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a library, if it is a single js file. Anyway, since the numbers are decimal you can pad them (their string representation) with trailing zeros so that they're all same length, then compare the portion before decimal as number and latter as string. But use a library.

Comment: @DaveNewton I hadn't considered that. I guess I assumed that it wouldn't be broken up in a way that would make that easy. In addition, those 3 libs were created before 2015. `bigint` seems to have been introduced in ES2020 which probably made *parts* of those libs redundant. I thought the same might hold true wrt my question.

Comment: If you make the numbers into a string and then split by . it should be fairly easy to compare "1000" > "100" is true after all.
Then add zeroes to the decimal with the least numbers. once they have the same number of digits they can be compared the same way.

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, where are numbers that big coming from? JavaScript numbers aren't different from 64-bit numbers in other languages; it's a hardware standard. (*edit* - could be from some "BigDecimal" system, as in Java or whatever)